# Segmentation fault on instationation of more than 1 object

Tags: c++, oop, class, graph, instantiation

I have a class called "Vertex.hpp" which is as follows:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "Edge.hpp"
 #include <vector>
   using namespace std;

/** A class, instances of which are nodes in an HCTree.
 */
class Vertex {
public:
Vertex(char * str){
 *name=*str;
 }

vector<Vertex*> adjecency_list;
vector<Edge*> edge_weights;
char *name;

 };

#endif
```

When I instantiate an object of type Vector as follows:

```
 Vertex *first_read;
 Vertex *second_read;

  in.getline(input,256);

  str=strtok(input," ");
  first_read->name=str;


  str=strtok(NULL, " ");
  second_read->name=str;
```

A segmentation fault occurs when more than 1 object of type Vector is instantiated. Why would this occur if more than 1 object is instantiated, and how can i allow multiple objects to be instantiated?

Comment: Please use `std::string`. That's not the way to use C strings (or pointers) at all. A [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would really help.

Comment: `first_read` and `second_read` are pointers to `Vertex` and are uninitialized (in the code you quote). Hence the crash.

Comment: Lots wrong, remove the "using namespace std" from the header, quit dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (name - in the constructor), uninitialized first_read and second_read.  Start with some basic pointer usage and then revisit this.

Comment: @RyanGuthrie: No, no, no, please don't start with *any* pointer usage!

Comment: @Kerrek SB when it comes to learning C++ (which includes C), and this looks like homework, it is important to know how pointers work and not just use high level abstractions to hide that information.

Comment: @RyanGuthrie: I'm not sure about that. Sometimes I think that people would write better code if they *didn't* know what pointers were and just didn't use them. Pointers should be an *advanced* topic if you want to take a low level of control because you know what you're doing...

Answer (score 2):

```
*name=*str;
```

You cannot dereference a pointer until you first make it point to something.

You probably meant something like:

```
Vertex(char * str) {
    name=strdup(str);
}
```

But you should really be using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 0):

I think the way how you copy strings is wrong.

```
*name=*str;
```

Both `name` ans `str` are of type char*. You are dereferencing those pointers. This means you look at the position at the memory where they point and interpret it as char.

When you call it first time something is at location pointed by `str` and first character of it is copied to random address (as you never initialized `name`).

Second time you are not so lucky. `strtok` called on NULL return NULL [strtok at cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

Now you tried to work with memorry pointed by null pointer and it is bad.

You need to allocate memory for `name` and use proper copy function.

```
name = new char[SomeMaxLenght];
strcpy(name, str);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very C way of doing things, which is incredibly non recommended in modern C++. Remember, C++ should be treated as a *different language*, not a strict superset of C.

First things first, you should really get a good book by looking at [that list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), as you seem to be missing many basics.

As for your problem, the main issue is that `name` is uninitialized, so you run into what is called *undefined behavior* (i.e. anything can happen; in your case it crashes on the second instantiation). I could go in depth on how to fix it by dynamically allocating memory, but why bother? Just use a `std::string`:

```
class Vertex {
    std::string name; // string instead of char *
public:
    Vertex(const std::string &str) { // pass by const reference
        name = str; // I should really use an initializer list there, but oh well
    }

    // the rest of the class is the same
};
```

See how that's simpler? Now you don't have to mess around with pointers, which are painful to use. So, in short: use the standard library. And get a good book. Really.

Comment: So, in short: Use the standard and public libraries? :)

Comment: @sehe Yeah, that was a pretty huge buildup just for that punchline. Although _at least_ I'm not suggesting pointers like everyone else around here.

Comment: Maybe better to use the constructor initializer list?